# How to play MP3's from socket connections in Flash AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, sockets, mp3

How to play mp3's from socket connections in Flash AS3?

I have some simple programm which is listening to some port (TCP).

I connect to it using as3 sockets and it starts sending me mp3 data

How to play that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the start her: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/dynamic_sound_generation/. Though I am not aware of any way to decode the mp3 from bytes in as3. Of cause the functionality must be somewhere in Flash Player, but I am not sure if it is exposed in AS3.
Though properly someone else tried to this before, so there might be a ready solution out there.
But i would bet more on you other related question.